# Is it okay to extend to MainActivity from a JavaScriptInterface to avoid non-static errors?

Tags: android

I have one activity with a webview in it. 
When the user interacts with the webview, it does this through the JavaScriptInterface so both the app and webview can interact with each other.
I believe the class is by default static, so I've found not too much can be done without it extending MainActivity.

```
public class JSInterface extends MainActivity {

    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    JSInterface(Context context, MainActivity mActivity) {
        mainActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void someMethod() {
        mainActivityMethod(webViewData);
    }

    // other methods

}
```

In my MainActivity I have:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
JSInterface JSInterface = new JSInterface(this, this);

//other methods called by JSInterface, e.g.
@Override
public void mainActivityMethod(String webViewData) {
    // do something with data
}
```

So I've found by extending to MainActivity from JSInterface, I can call normal (non-static) methods from MainActivity which is very much a necessity.
If I don't extend it to MainActivity, it seems to be a static class and I get this error when trying to call MainActivity methods or reference anything not static:

```
Non-static method someMethod() cannot be referenced from a static context.
```

It works as it is, but I feel like this isn't the best way to go about it.
Am I right?
What would be the 'best' way to do this? Or other ways, as best is subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I feel like this isn't the best way to go about it

Never create a subclass of `Activity` unless you are going to start it with `startActivity()`.

> What would be the 'best' way to do this?

One option is simple composition, getting rid of the improper inheritance:

```
public class JSInterface {
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    JSInterface(MainActivity mActivity) {
        mainActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void someMethod() {
        mainActivity.something(webViewData);
    }

    // other methods

}
```

Another is a nested class. In [this sample activity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/WebKit/GeoWeb1/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/geoweb/GeoWebOne.java), `Locater` is a nested class inside of my `GeoWebOne` activity, and therefore `Locater` can call methods and access fields in `GeoWebOne`. The simple composition approach is a better answer, though a nested class will work.

Comment: That worked great! So set the reference to the mainactivity then do it all through that instance. Thanks for the clarification on when to extend to activities.